# Preserve anonymous types when linking

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have some code that uses reflection on anonymous types to fill data into a URI pattern, like so:

```
var uri = UriUtility.FromPattern("/{action}/{id}.{contentType}", new {
    action = "foo",
    id = 1234,
    contentType = "xml"
});
```

When I use the MonoTouch option to "link all assemblies", the anonymous type members get stripped and my code fails at runtime. Is there a way to tell the MonoTouch linker to preserve all members of anonymous types?

**Update**

Here is a complete test case demonstrating the problem. The test passes with when linking SDK assemblies only, and it fails when linking all assemblies.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace LinkerTests.iOS
{
    [Preserve(AllMembers = true)]
    [TestFixture]
    public class AnonymousTypeTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            var str = string.Join(",", AnonymousTypeUtil.GetProperties(new { a = "a", b = "b" }));
            Assert.AreEqual("a=a,b=b", str);
        }
    }

    internal static class AnonymousTypeUtil
    {
        public static IEnumerable<string> GetProperties(object o)
        {
            foreach (var property in o.GetType().GetRuntimeProperties())
            {
                object value = property.GetValue(o);
                yield return property.Name + "=" + value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your problems are related to the fact that anonymous types are actually internal, and not public, and so you won't be able to refer to the type from other assemblies.  I'd also like to throw in the fact that I would strongly advise you against using this particular coding pattern.  You shouldn't be treating the names of members as data; use pairs of strings instead.

Comment: I don't think internal vs public has anything to do with it. The linker removes public members and types as well as internal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received confirmation from Xamarin that this is not currently possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's a linker issue, i.e. the three fields are assigned/used and won't be removed by the linker) at least it is not an issue with anonymous types.

With the linker enabled (link all) this is what I see inside Xamarin Studio (immediate window):

```
> ? o
{{ action = foo, id = 1234, contentType = xml }}
```

However, like mentioned by @Servy, those fields are **not** public (and that's the compiler, not the linker that does so). You need to access them as non public fields in your reflecting code, e.g.

```
> o.GetType ().GetField ("<action>", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
{System.String <action>}
    Attributes: System.Reflection.FieldAttributes.InitOnly|System.Reflection.FieldAttributes.Private
    DeclaringType: {<>__AnonType0`3[System.String,System.Int32,System.String]}
    FieldHandle: {System.RuntimeFieldHandle}
    FieldType: {System.String}
    IsInitOnly: true
    IsLiteral: false
    IsNotSerialized: false
    IsPrivate: true
    IsStatic: false
    MemberType: 4
    MetadataToken: 67108914
    Name: "<action>"
    ReflectedType: {<>__AnonType0`3[System.String,System.Int32,System.String]}
    Non-public members:
```

I cannot diagnose this any further without knowing what (and how) `UriUtility.FromPattern` does it's work using reflection. You might want to update your question and/or file a [bug report](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) with a complete test case.

OTOH I'm certain that **this** example should work properly with the linker and reflection (but using reflection can still be tricky when enabling the linker since static analysis cannot precisely determine what's being used).

Comment: I assume it is the public readonly getters that are removed by the linker. I have filed a bug report. https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=23355